# Date formatting Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template, profile, attribute-group

I want to fetch date variable on a email in marketing cloud from a data extension that contains personalized dates. Also, when I preview the email, the date is displayed in the US format. I am looking to have the date displayed as dd mm yyyy (i.e in email the date should be 01 January 2018), how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use date formatting function here.

```
%%[
VAR @date, @email
SET @email = EmailAddress /*This is the column name for email address that you have used in your DE*/
SET @date = Lookup('Data Extension name here','Date column name here that you have used in your Data Extension','Email Address column name here that you have used in your Data Extension',@email) /*To populate date value from your DE for the user to whom email will be sent*/
]%%

%%=FormatDate("@date", "DD MMMM YYYY")=%%
```

Please refer to this link for Date formatting function:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/dateTimeFormatting.htm

Please refer to this link for Lookup function:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookup.htm

Comment: Thank you Krati i will look up the links you gave me and try your solution.

Answer (score 1):

The date formatting function you provided is not returning any value when I go to preview my email send.

The below was used:

```
    %%[
    VAR @date, @email
    SET @email = Email (Email is the column name for email address in my DE)
    SET @date = Lookup('DE Name','Date column name','Email',@email) 
    ]%%

%%=FormatDate("@date", "DD MMMM YYYY")=%%
```

?

Comment: did you replace `Email` and `Date column name` with the correct attributes inside of your Data Extension? It sounds like your lookup is returning a null result.  For instance, you could replace `Email` with `AttributeValue("emailaddr")` using the SFMC personalization string that pulls the associated sendable email address with that send.

Comment: Hi Yes I did,  Email is "Email" in my data extension and date column was replaced with the attribute value using the personalisation string. I ended up uploading file in CRM as a text file, sync it to MC and using the personalisation in profile attribute as a workaround.